# How can I set a breakpoint in .NET Framework source code using Visual Studio 2010 Express?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2010, debug-symbols

I need to set a breakpoint in System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule.OnPostAcquireRequestState and then step into some of the System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceData methods.

But I only have Visual Web Developer 2010 Express (or other Express SKUs). I have configured the Microsoft Symbol Server and unchecked the *Just My Code* option. I can see that the symbols for System.Web.Extensions are downloaded and cached.

However, this version of Visual Studio doesn't have the breakpoints window, so I don't see a good way to set the breakpoint.

Am I just out of luck or is there another way to set a breakpoint in this method? It seems the option for the symbol server is pointless without the option to set a breakpoint.

Comment: Does it have the Ctrl+B keyboard shortcut for bringing up the breakpoint window? If it does, you should be able to input the FQN of the method (ie. namespace.classname.methodname)... Hmm, or perhaps not, I was unable to make one in the professional edition to Console.WriteLine, perhaps it can't be done with the BCL.

Comment: No Ctrl+B shortcut in Visual Web Developer Express

Comment: Debug -> (Window) -> Breakpoints

Answer (score -5):

paste this line in your code,  after the line where you want to get debug info.
Haven't tried it but should work.
`System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The question states that the breakpoint is required in `System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule.OnPostAcquireRequestState` - a system area, not their own code, so a code amendment is not possible.  I have not personally downvoted, bit harsh on a new user.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit post appears in [Late Answers](http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers) (and maybe in Low Quality) review queue and words **"Haven't tried it"** likely trigger negative feedback strong enough for downvoters to come over -1 penalty for answers (I didn't DV for the record)

Comment: I'll upvote this.  Yes it may not be possible with .net framework code as OP, but while I use this for concept with JavaScript, I didn't think it was available for c#.